# 1980s movie or TV show where a woman is turned into a Raggedy ann-like doll at the end

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I must have been about 6 when I saw this show; it was late at night, and seemed more for adults, so the details are vague. From what I remember:

- There was a woman with some type of supernatural power, and she was stalking/in a relationship/haunting a man.
- The man reminded me of William Katts from *House* but *perhaps* was a bit younger.
- I can't be certain if she was *turned* into the doll, if it was some type of focus for her power, of if it was just a symbol of sorts.
- At the end of the movie, the last shot was on the doll, and I *think* they may have been in a store of sorts.

This may well have been a TV show, like *Tales from the Darkside* , but I don't remember correctly; from the sets and [comparatively] high definition, it *looked* somewhat more expansive than an average episode, and as a kid at the time who just happened on to it on cable one night, I had no reference point.

Comment: For some reason this makes me think of the 1979 film [*Quincy's Quest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quincy%27s_Quest).

Comment: @DanielRoseman  think i'm familiar with that one, where the toys wanted to get to Santa to stop from being destroyed or something. No.... no this felt explicitly more like a "supernatural thriller" kind of thing.

Comment: Might have been the _Twilight Zone_ reboot series, or the [1983 movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_Zone:_The_Movie), where they redid "[It's a Good Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Good_Life_(The_Twilight_Zone))" complete with a cameo from Bill Mumy.

Comment: @Spencer I was a _TZ_ fan even _then_ my friend; I would have recognized it's aesthetics, even as a kid. The guy _did_ remind me of William Kattz from _House_ though, or the guy who was Bradley Brinkman in that movie _Hunk_. Does that help at all?

Comment: Do you mean [William Katt](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001411/), who appeared in one episode of _House_ in 2006?

Comment: @Spencer No no, I mean the curly haired guy from 1979's _Carrie_ and the 1980s horror comedy **House** about a haunted manor.

Comment: Yes, that's the same [William Katt](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091223/).  BTW _[Carrie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074285/)_ was released in 1976, not 1979,

Comment: He was in [a 1988 episode of the _Alfred Hitchcock Presents_ reboot](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0508371/) but it was a McGuffin-centered thriller and nothing to do with SF.